# How to find a chavrusa for a difficult topic

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, rabbis, adult-learning, chavrusa

How would one go about finding a rabbi/rav with whom to have a chavrusa if one is picky and has specific needs -- i.e., for someone with particular qualities, or who is highly learned in a niche area? Assume one is not in a yeshiva or seminary, and one does not want to work with the rabbi of one's community/shul. Obviously, asking around--i.e., asking that very rabbi--would be a good way to start. But is there any way to go about finding a chavrusa who meets specific requirements?

Comment: If you don't mind over the phone learning, try http://www.jnet.org/ they will try to meet your requirements.

Comment: This question seems primarily opinion based.

Comment: Asking around with friends and rabbis does seem to be the only universally applicable advice. Different learning institutions might have localized services available (sign up sheets, etc.)

Comment: @mevaqesh What? It's a request for practical advice.

Comment: Does it not say somewhere that you need to travel to learn Torah, you are looking for someone "who is highly learned in a niche area" would that not be a teacher?

Comment: You may ask me about what you are looking for specifically, and I can tell you if I know someone that can help. :) davidariel25@gmail.com I have helped a couple people here before BH. :)

Comment: https://www.partnersintorah.org/ might be a good solution if this is still relevant